# MacBook Pro ZSH terminal prompt

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Hope someone would help. Bought new MacBook Pro 2020 yesterday and it has `ZSH` by default not `bash` and $ sign also disappeared. I can see there are two files in bin folder which are bash and zsh.

Is there any way I can get rid of MBP in my prompt and change my prompt name and also get back $ sign as well? please see attached pic what I am talking about. [image: terminal image]

Update

I managed to change prompt by making a new file .zshrc in home dir and adding prompt properties `PROMPT='%(?.%F{green}Azam.%F{blue}?%?)%f %B%F{240}%0~%f%b %#'`. Now my prompt looking fine but its output `?127` when `command not found`. Please let me know how I can fix this so it should drop back to default prompt? [image: new command prompt pic]

Comment: You can customise the prompt: https://scriptingosx.com/2019/07/moving-to-zsh-06-customizing-the-zsh-prompt/

Comment: Read `man zshall`, or specifically for information on configuring the prompt, see `man zshmisc`.

Comment: You can also switch back to `bash` if you really want to; `zsh` is just the *default*. Just like `zsh` has been *available* for years, `bash` is still available, and you can always install a modern version of `bash` as well. (I really wouldn't recommend sticking with the version of `bash` that ships with macOS.)

Comment: (Note that changing your login shell to something you install yourself may require editing `/etc/shells`, which may involve jumping through some additional hoops.)

Comment: Hi guys, I updated my question, please help me to change the output , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
# without color
export PS1='%n %~ %(!.#.$) '

# with color
export PROMPT='%(?.%F{green}%n.%F{blue}?%?)%f %B%F{240}%~%f%b %(!.#.$) '

# remove return value (like 127) from prompt
export PROMPT='%F{green}%n%f %B%F{240}%~%f%b %(!.#.$) '
```

`PS1` is equivalent to `PROMPT` in zsh. Use whichever you want.

References

- [ZSH Prompt Expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Prompt-Expansion)

Comment: Thank you for this. Please check 2nd image and let me know how to fix `command not found` output.

Comment: @Webappsdeva `export PROMPT='%F{green}%n%f %B%F{240}%~%f%b %(!.#.$) '`