# issue with macOs monterey terminal (zsh)

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, macos-monterey

i am using a macOs Monterey latest version

my terminal is zsh

it looks like user@users-MacBook-Pro ~ %

I noticed most videos tend to show a $ dollar sign at the end instead of % percentage which is what i have

is my terminal not in the correct setting or is okay for % sign at the end ?

confused , as i am learning how to use terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MacBook Pro ZSH terminal prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935752/macbook-pro-zsh-terminal-prompt)

Comment: Most videos use `bash` for which the default prompt usually ends with `$` or `#`. It won't affect anything. However, if the tutorials are bash-specific (such as writing bash scripts) it is recommended to switch to bash instead.

Answer (score 0):

That is how the prompt of the zsh shell is. What you are seeing in your videos is the prompt of a bash shell which tipically ends in # for root and $ for all the other users.

This is not an issue per se, but it could be if the commands or scripts used in the videos rely on special features of the bash shell. You have to consult the documentation of what you are about to use in order to find out if there are incompatibilities.

Since switching to a temporary shell is simple, you could use bash when you watch a video that assumes it is your shell.